# swift 3 - can not convert string to date

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

No matter what I do, I can not convert an RSSs pubDate (which is a string of course) into a `Date`.

Here is the date String: `Sun, 02 Apr 2017 19:31:18 GMT`

Here is my code:

```
private var dateBuffer: Date {
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz"
    let date = formatter.date(from: buffers["pubDate"]!) //<-date comes back nil
    return date! //<-program crashes
}
```

`date` always returns `nil`. What maybe the problem??

Comment: No, it does not work. The mistake was using "hh" for hour instead of "HH" as @Ahamd F and Palle have stated. Many thanks to them..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are *pretty sure* that `buffers["pubDate"]!` is equal to "Sun, 02 Apr 2017 19:31:18 GMT" (or any date with the same format), then it should be:

```
var dateBuffer: Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
    let date = formatter.date(from: buffers["pubDate"]!)
    return date!
}
```

Note that the difference is `HH:mm:ss` instead of `hh:mm:ss`. For reading the hours as 24-clock convention, you should use `HH`.

Also, to be more safe -from any unexpected crash-, I'd suggest to do some *optional binding*, as follows:

```
var dateBuffer: Date? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    let str:String? = "Sun, 02 Apr 2017 19:31:18 GMT"

    formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
    if let pubDate = buffers["pubDate"], let date = formatter.date(from: pubDate) {
        return date
    }

    return nil
}

if let myDate = dateBuffer {
    print(myDate)
}
```

Comment: Shukran mister Ahmad, problem solved

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using another language / locale than English but the name of your Weekday is in English ("Sun").

The formatter will work as expected, if you set the locale to English:

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
```

Also, the format must be `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz` (with capital H because of 24 hour time)

Comment: It's not a locale issue, its about the format itself, I'm not the downvoter btw :)

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. It works for me, if both the locale is changed and the format is updated to `HH` instead of `hh`.

Comment: Yes, it was the issue with the hour, not the locale. I am actually testing it with New York Times. I guess it cant get more standard